# Uploading images in spring using react

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios

how to solevt he issue with status 415 in spring?

I am trying to upload the images in DB with react, but all the time receive the errors:

in Spring console :

```
Content-Type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryMzjfDQXfdupeZNW2;charset=UTF-8' is not supported
```

in Browser console:

```
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 415', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

I am trying to add the Item in DB and Images in related DB. Where ID of items are added with images. In the Spring I created the entities for images and items. In Items entity I created the method which add the images, which are received with item, as entity and put them in DB :

```
private Image toImageEntity(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        Image image = new Image();
        image.setImageName(file.getName());
        image.setOriginalFileName(file.getOriginalFilename());
        image.setContentType(file.getContentType());
        image.setSize(file.getSize());
        image.setBytes(file.getBytes());
        return image;
    }
```

In the Item entities I receive the images and Item body as params :

```
@PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveAsset(@RequestBody Assets assets,
                                            @RequestParam MultipartFile file1,
                                            @RequestParam MultipartFile file2,
                                            @RequestParam MultipartFile file3)  throws IOException {

        Image image1;
        Image image2;
        Image image3;

        if(file1.getSize() != 0){
            image1 = toImageEntity(file1);
            image1.setPreviewImage(true);
            assets.addImageToItemName(image1);
        }
        if(file2.getSize() != 0){
            image2 = toImageEntity(file2);
            assets.addImageToItemName(image2);
        }
        if(file3.getSize() != 0){
            image3 = toImageEntity(file3);
            assets.addImageToItemName(image3);
        }

        System.out.println(assets);

        Assets itemFromDB = assetsRepository.save(assets);
        itemFromDB.setPreviewImageId(itemFromDB.getImages().get(0).getId());
        assetsRepository.save(assets);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

In react I created the method for send the data to Spring :

```
const saveAsset = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('assettype', assettype)
        formData.append('assetBrand', assetBrand)
        formData.append('assetModel', assetModel)
        formData.append('file1', image1)
        formData.append('file2', image2)
        formData.append('file3', image3)

        const asset = {
            assettype,
            assetBrand,
            assetModel,
        }

         const file1 = {
        image1
    }
    const file2 = {
        image2
    }
    const file3 = {
        image3
    }
    axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "http://localhost:8082/api/assets",
        data: {
            asset,
            file1,
            file2,
            file3
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        console.log(res.headers)
        console.log(res.request)
        console.log(res.status)
    })
    }
```

If I remove the line with `headers`:

```
headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
```

from axios, the console of browser show me error 500, but Spring console shows - that current is not multipart request.

in form tag I put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` but any way I receive the errors.

I tried post with `FormData`, or `postForm` with a `FileList` but I receive the error status 415

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your controller:

`@RequestBody` means to parse JSON data into map or java beans and only support content type is "application/json;charset=UTF-8"

Maybe you can try with `@ModelAttribute`:

```
    @PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveAsset(@ModelAttribute Assets assets,
                                            @RequestParam MultipartFile file1,
                                            @RequestParam MultipartFile file2,
                                            @RequestParam MultipartFile file3)  throws IOException {
```